# Trouble setting time format in chart.js 3.9.1

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I am currently trying to format some time but I am having some issues finding how to format my data in the exact way I need to. I was able to utilize the time scale and set a format but it's not what I entered for my format struct and I'm not sure why. Also on top of that the data is incrementing strangely instead of just moving to the next spot in the labels array. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Heres my code for my options:

```
scales: {
        x: {
          stacked: true,
          position: 'bottom',
          type: chartType,
          time:{
            format:'DD-HH:MM:SS'
          },
          adapters: { 
            date: {
              locale: enUS, 
            },
          }, 
        },
    },
```

Then here you can see how the data is incrementing:

[image]

The data should be incremented by 5 minutes which is why I am confused why it's incrementing every second instead, an example is `[00-00:05:00,00-00:10:00....]` I am using chart.js 3.9.1.

If it's possible can I just place my labels below as strings?

**Update:**

I know that the reason the chart is incrementing so weirdly is that I am apparently giving an invalid date format so it's defaulting to a preset one. So my new question is, is it possible for me to use strings on my x-axis or create a custom date format?

Secondly, I saw that the format for the date in chart.js is `YYYY:MM:DD` or `HH:MM:SS`. Would it be possible for me to create a format of `DD:HH:MM:SS`?

Final Update:

```
scales: {
    x: {
      stacked: true,
      position: 'bottom',
      type: chartType,
      time:{
        displayFormats: {
          'millisecond': 'dd-HH:MM:SS',
          'second': 'dd-HH:MM:SS',
          'minute': 'dd-HH:MM:SS',
          'hour': 'dd-HH:MM:SS',
          'day': 'dd-HH:MM:SS',
          'week': 'dd-HH:MM:SS',
          'month': 'dd-HH:MM:SS',
          'quarter': 'dd-HH:MM:SS',
          'year': 'dd-HH:MM:SS'
        }
      },
      adapters: { 
        date: {
          locale: enUS, 
        },
      }, 
    },
},
```

In order to create a custom format for your x scale you simply need to add the displayFormat attribute inside of your scale and lay out the exact format you want. Then in order to avoid having your data incorrectly format as I did you need to make sure that you formatted your data in a way that chartjs will accept. An easy way to do that is simply pass your data through Date.parse() to double-check, obviously only do this in your testing phase.

Comment: Yes for all the questions. But, having a look to your code, what's the value of "chartType" that you are assigning to scales.x.type?

Comment: You could use "parser" option of time scale and setting the format you have used in your data points. The time.format that you set is not an configuration options of time scales, AFA I see. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.9.1/axes/cartesian/time.html

Comment: To customize your labels (ticks) you could use ticks.callback options. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.9.1/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats

Comment: @user2057925 The chartType is just a state I am changing when I render specific datasets. In some cases I use linear when implementing this I will be using timeseries.